# Import template in Vuejs single file component as an external HTML file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I am working on a Vuejs project where i use vue-property-decorator in single file components and i want to be able to import the template from an external html (or different) file. I can't seem to find any solution for this and am wondering if this is even possible.

Ideally I want to import the template like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component({
  template: "Header.html"
})
export default class App extends Vue {
  @Prop()
  public msg!: string;
  private test: string = "(green)";
  private classAdded: boolean = false;

  private addClass() {
    this.classAdded = !this.classAdded;
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "./Header.scss";
</style>
```

But then my console outputs this:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Component template requires a root element, rather than just text.

1  |  Header.html
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^

found in

---> <App> at src/components/Header/Header.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
```

How can I investigate this issue?

Comment: the [excellent vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#Example-Sandbox) has a link to an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9) of how one uses SFC

Comment: I think you need some <div></div> tags in your header.html, maybe thats the problem

Comment: I know how SFC's work. I just wanted to be able to externalize the HTML. I found a simple solution that works for me just fine now.

Comment: @Loki `template: "Header.html"` means the template is the exact string `"Header.html"` - vue won't fetch header.html for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! Not in the desired way but it works for me! Turns out you can put a `src` attribute to your `<template></template>` as a reference to the HTML. In my case: `<template src="./Header.html"></template>`

Thanks for thinking along!